# Access the regularization paths obtained from ElasticNetCV in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I would like to get these plots:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_coordinate_descent_path.html

from an elastic net I have already trained.
The example does

```
from sklearn.linear_model import lasso_path, enet_path
from sklearn import datasets

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data
print("Computing regularization path using the elastic net...")
alphas_enet, coefs_enet, _ = enet_path(
    X, y, eps=eps, l1_ratio=0.8, fit_intercept=False)
```

which basically requires recomputing from `X,y` the whole model.
Unfortunately, I do not have `X,y`.

In the training I have used `sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV` which returns:

```
coef_ : array, shape (n_features,) | (n_targets, n_features)

    parameter vector (w in the cost function formula)

mse_path_ : array, shape (n_l1_ratio, n_alpha, n_folds)

Mean square error for the test set on each fold, varying l1_ratio and alpha.
```

while I would need  parameter vector varying l1_ratio and alpha.

Can this be done without recomputation? It would be a tremendous waste of time as those coef_paths are actually calculated already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Not once it is fit.

### Long answer

If you look through the source code for [`ElasticNetCV`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L1382), you will see that within the fit method the class is calling [`enet_path`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L268), but with `alphas` set to the value of alpha initialized in `ElasticNet` (default 1.0) which is set by the value of alphas in `ElasticNetCV` which will end up being a single value. So instead of calculating the coefficients for the default 100 values of alpha that allow you to create the path graphs, you only get the one for each value of alpha you set in your CV. That being said you could initialize the alphas in your CV to mimic the 100 default in `enet_path` and then combine the coefficients from each fold, but this would be rather long running. As you mentioned you have already fit the CV this is not an option.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the answer. I was hoping I had missed some undocumented feature. In my case, the EN was already fit with way more than the 100 default alpha values, so the ones set in CV were really sufficient to reproduce the graph. I think this is a design error, as the coefficients are already calculated for each fold and for each alpha but they are not stored/returned to the caller

Comment: In conclusion, I have to get back X,y and retrain